# Side-effect: TextBox GotFocus issue with async programming

Tags: xaml, asynchronous, windows-runtime, mqtt

I've created a WP 8.1 app ([MQTT Tester](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/mqtt-tester/36661f1f-c072-492f-b14b-c75e96a8ab25)) for testing MQTT.

I've based the app on the great work done with the [M2MQTT Client](https://m2mqtt.wordpress.com/). Thanks!

When using the the Connect feature of the MqttClient I'd like to do this asyncronously. To do this I created this extension:

```
public static class MqttClientEx
{
    public static async Task<byte> ConnectAsync(this MqttClient client, 
        string clientId, 
        string username, 
        string password,
        bool cleanSession,
        ushort keepAlivePeriod,
        bool willRetain = false,
        byte willQosLevel = 0,
        bool willFlag = false,
        string willTopic = "",
        string willMessage = "")
    {
        var t = Task.Run(() => 
        {
            return client.Connect(
                    clientId: clientId,
                    username: username,
                    password: password,
                    willRetain: willRetain,
                    willQosLevel: willQosLevel,
                    willFlag: willFlag,
                    willTopic: willTopic,
                    willMessage: willMessage,
                    cleanSession: cleanSession,
                    keepAlivePeriod: keepAlivePeriod);
        });
        return await t;
    }
}
```

This ensures that the UI thread is responsive even in the case where MQTT Connect takes a little while. It also ensures that the UI thread does not lock up in the case where the user have typed a wrong mqtt broker address or the broker is not available.

It works, but it also introduces a side-effect that I don't understand and that I'm unable to mitigate:

When I press the Subscribe Button (part of the UI) the broker Textbox gets focus?! Why, I have no idea?

This is super annoying because the on-screen keyboards comes up and covers the output window each time the Subscribe button is pressed and to remove it the user need to press somewhere else on the UI de-focus the Textbox again.

It seems that introducing the *await Task.Run(() => ...* is what causes this. If I call the MqttClient.Connect syncronously then the TextBox does not get focus.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code which calls ConnectAsync along with the related XAML?

Comment: Thanks for asking. It turned out to be rather tricky and I still don't understand why I saw this behavior and hence I'm not really able to explain it. Anyway I found a work-around. If you'd still like to look at it I'd be happy to post the whole app on Github tommorrow and point out exactly what I changed to mitigated the issue? I'm afraid that posting more bits and pieces of the code here would not really help to create clearity by itself.